# Saving image from url to disk not working

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to download an image from an url in my app, so that it can be used by the Today Extension.

So I call `[self downloadImageFromUrl:imageOne];`, which uses this method:

```
- (void)downloadImageFromUrl:(NSString *)url {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *storeUrl = [fileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.myapp.TodayExtensionDefaults"];
        NSString *path = [storeUrl absoluteString];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test/imageOne.png"];

        NSLog(@"Path is %@", path);

        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
        UIImage *image = responseObject;

        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
    }];

    [requestOperation start];
}
```

So when I run this, everything executes fine. I get no errors. Yet, when I go to the folder logged in the simulator, no file is present. The error I get from the write action is `Write returned error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)`. And so I changed the write action to:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@. %s, %i", error.localizedDescription, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    }
}

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

But I still get `Write returned error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)`

Comment: What's the output of `NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);`? I assume it's a bunch of hexa numbers, which isn't an `UIImage`... Also, have you tried creating an image view and displaying the image in that? The problem might (and probably isn't) with `writeToPath:automatically`

Comment: It does output  `<UIImage: 0x7b3c1aa0>, {318, 178}` and a `UIImageView` displays the image correct.

Comment: So I don't know why I'm getting downvoted...

Comment: writeToFile return value?

Comment: Well how do you test/catch a return value of a function?... How do you test the return value of: `[storeUrl absoluteString];`? Also you could try using `writeToFile:options:error:` with `DataWritingAtomic` as option and giving an NSError** object to it to see if any error ocurres.

Comment: @Rob Yes, I created it.

Comment: `Write returned error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)` I'll edit the question.

Comment: Well, what the hell. Changing it to `path` actually fixed everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grabbing the `absoluteString` (which includes the scheme, amongst other things):

```
NSString *path = [storeUrl absoluteString];
```

I believe you intended the `path`:

```
NSString *path = [storeUrl path];
```